# Cast to IDictionary

Tags: c#, idictionary

The function below returns a type of Dynamic, what is the most efficient way to cast it to  IDictionary

```
 public dynamic GetEntities(string entityName, string entityField)
```

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use `var dictionary = (IDictionary)GetEntities(...);`?

Comment: What are the type-parameters of the dictionary? `IDictionary<string, string>`?

Comment: @user1842828 Who knows what's behind the `dynamic`-typed object...? And, after all, this wouldn't be a cast but a **conversion**

Comment: If you safely know you have an IDictionary, why use dynamic at all?

Comment: Matías Fidemraizer wrote the problem. Could you *please* post the code of `GetEntities`?

Comment: I'm assuming this is related to this previous question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13592065/convert-type-system-dynamic-dynamicobject-to-system-collections-ienumerable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd probably go with the `as` operator.

```
var result = GetEntities("blah", "blahblah") as IDictionary<string,string>;
```

Then do a `null` check.

**UPDATE**

In regards to the "efficient" part of your question, I think `as` may be pretty efficient compared to some other paths you could take:

1. You could just blindly cast it to `IDictionary<string,string>` and
   then catch the exception, but using exceptions for control flow
   isn't a good idea and is expensive.
2. You could use a convention like `expression is type ? (type)expression : (type)null`, but in this case, you evaluate
   `expression` twice (but you do get a null if the expected type isn't
   the type that expression returns).  So you're doing double
   evaluations.
3. `as` is only good for reference or boxing conversions, not to perform user-defined conversions, so if you need that, then `as`
   isn't for you.

See [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cscsdfbt%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) on MSDN.

**UPDATE 2**

I made an assumption on the key/value types of the `IDictionary`.  You could just use `IDictionary` after `as` instead of specifying the generic type parameters.  I guess it depends on what you're expecting.

Hope this helps.

Comment: are you sure underling type of dynamic is dictionary?

Comment: @ArsenMkrt: No, that's why he is using `as` in the first place.

Comment: But, think he want to convert to dictionary, any dynamic type, like [propertyname, value], agree the question doesn't clarify this part

Comment: I made an assumption based on the input types to the OP's method.

Answer (score 0):

```
var dict = GetEntities(entityName, entityField) as IDictionary
```

or

```
var dict = GetEntities(entityName, entityField) as IDictionary<string,string>
```

Comment: are you sure underling type of dynamic is dictionary?

Comment: it has to be assumed. Otherwise type check will be needed first

Comment: @user1842828 If you do the above check for dict != null before invoking any members from it or you'll get a null exception if the cast fails.

Comment: @ArsenMkrt: You are using `as` when you are **not** sure that the object has the expected type.

Comment: as I said, I think question mean to convert any dynamic to dictionary like propertyName, Value. but it is not clear

Answer (score 0):

This way:

```
IDictionary dictionary = GetEntities("", "") as IDictionary;
```

Then either `dictionary` will be your object, or it will be null - depending on result type of `GetEntities`.

Answer (score 0):

```
IDictionary dict = GetEntities(name, field) as IDictionary;
```

Then check for `null` and everything's fine. If you don't want that `dict` is null, but it throws an exception instead, use

```
IDictionary dict = (IDictionary) GetEntities(name, field);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:-

```
 var dict = GetEntities(entityName, entityField) as IDictionary<string,string>
```

Comment: What if the types aren't `<string, string>`?

Comment: OP has provided the type as <string,string>? Is this wrong or am I am missing something?

Comment: Actually, no. He just wrote that it's a dictionary, the `string`s are only given as parameters in the function ;).

Comment: @looper:- Then probably IDictionary dict = (IDictionary) GetEntities(name, field); will work great. But I still think that my answer will resolve OP's query!!

Comment: You don't even know that the `dynamic` object is actually a dictionary, let alone what the generic arguments of it might be.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends what is the underling type of dynamic

If it is converted to dynamic from IDictionary, you can simply cast it

```
var dict = GetEntities(entityName, entityField) as IDictionary
```

if not, things become complicated, and it is not always possible to do

In this case you first need to check underling type by calling `GetType` method, if it is managed type and not DynamicObject, you are lucky, use reflection, if it is DynamicObject, I don't think there is any way to convert it to dictionary, because it may have custom implementation and even reflection doesn't work in this case